# How to store form data in an ajax variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with one text field. This form is submitted using ajax. While submitting, I want to save the data in the textfield in one of ajax variables too. Below is my code.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
 $("button#submit").click(function(){
         $.ajax({

     type: "POST",
 url: "PastSurgicalCustomItem",
 data: $('form.form-horizontal').serialize(),
         success: function(msg){

        var $data = $('form.form-horizontal').serialize();

         var $firstDiv = $('<div></div>');
         $firstDiv.attr("class","col-md-3");


         var $secondDiv = $('<div></div>');
         $secondDiv.attr("class","checkbox history_checkbox_div");
         $secondDiv.appendTo($firstDiv);

         var $label = $('<label></label>');
         $label.appendTo($secondDiv);

         var $checkBox = $('<input></input>');
         $checkBox.attr("type","checkbox");
         $checkBox.attr("class","history_checkbox");
         $checkBox.attr("id",msg);
         $checkBox.appendTo($label);

         var $span = $('<span></span>');
         $span.text($data);
         $span.appendTo($label);

         $firstDiv.appendTo($('#customDiv'));


         },
 error: function(){
 alert("failure");
 }
       });
 });
});
</script>
```

But that didn't work well. If I insert the data "test7", then the `$data` variable will contain the below

```
textinput=&textarea=&customName=test7
```

How can I correctly get the data inside the textbox to an ajax variable? For more information, my application is designed using bootstrap.

Comment: Because you have used serialize() function. Plz refer to this documentation http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @hrs: If I remove `serialize` then I get `object`

Comment: How do you want to store it? In other words, what is your expected output format?

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: And what in your mind is "an ajax variable"? :)

Comment: @hrs: I want to store the "data" which was inserted to the "textbox". Not other information.Only the data inserted to the textbox. Since I have one textbox, this is the only data bieng submitted as well.

Comment: Only textbox? Not all the fields? Then you can store using objects name.

Comment: Then you can store in variable something like this
var variable_name= $(this).find('textarea[name="your_textarea_name"]').text();

Comment: Can't quite understand why you are using the data directly from the form in your callback rather than the form data that has been processed via ajax.

Comment: @EternalHour: You mean why I am not using the value returned by servlet response?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: @EternalHour: Servlet do some different processing using the given data, what it returns is an "id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get values of individual fields inside your form:

```
$('form.form-horizontal').find(':input[name="customName"]').val();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really appreciate it. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Then you can store in variable something like this

```
var variable_name= $(this).find('textarea[name="your_textarea_name"]').text();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really appreciate it. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) instead of serialize().

`serialize()` outputs a key/value string  `textinput=&textarea=&customName=test7`

`serializeArray()` outputs a JSON :

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
]
```

Comment: New way of doing it. +1 from me.